# Annotate django user queryset with group names

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Given that I have a django model that has a ForeignKey that is linked to itself.

```
class DjangoModel():

    [...]

    successor = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

I was able to write a custom django database function like this:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField
from django.db.models import Func


class IsNull(Func):
    """
    See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/
    """
    template = '%(expressions)s IS NULL'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['output_field'] = BooleanField()
        super(IsNull, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So I can do this:

```
queryset = DjangoModel.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.annotate(**{'is_latest': IsNull('successor')})
```

and if use `queryset.values()` .. I get

```
[{'pk': 1, is_latest': True}, {'pk': 2, 'is_latest': False}, ]
```

where `is_latest == True` when `successor` field is NULL for an object.

Now I want to do something similar, but have no idea where to start!

The bundled `django.contrib.auth.models.User` has a ManyToMany relations to `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` model

For my project, there are multiple user group types, e.g customer / marketing / finance etc

What I want to do.. is annotate a `User` queryset with `is_FOO` field where `FOO` is a group name. e.g `is_customer` or `is_marketing`

So if I use `.values()` on a queryset, I should get something like this:

```
[{'pk': 1, 'is_customer': True, 'is_marketing': False }, {'pk': 1, 'is_customer': True, 'is_marketing': True }]
```

The group name could be hardcoded, e.g

```
queryset.annotate(**{'is_customer': IsGroupMember('customer')})
```

I just need help with the `IsGroupMember` database function!

Is that even possible? Any hints or tips to get me started?

Any help will be genuinely appreciated.  Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have 2 solutions for the problem :-)**

Given that I'm using the django auth user model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and the group name I'm interested in:

```
CUSTOMER_GROUP_NAME = 'customer'
```

**Solution 1** — as suggested by Todor Velichkov in [django-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-users) google group.

Slightly modified version of his answer below:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL


def is_group_member(group_name):
    return RawSQL("""EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM `auth_group`
        WHERE `auth_group`.`name` = %s
            AND `auth_group`.`id` IN (
                SELECT `auth_user_groups`.`group_id`
                FROM `auth_user_groups`
                WHERE `auth_user_groups`.`user_id` = `auth_user`.`id`
            )
    )""", (group_name,), output_field=BooleanField())


qs1 = User.objects.all().annotate(is_customer=is_group_member(CUSTOMER_GROUP_NAME))
```

Link to original answer: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/BLCGZtUzEcY/w5w87frbBgAJ

---

I did some more research and learnt about django conditional expressions.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

**Solution 2** — using django expressions :-)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import BooleanField
from django.db.models import When, Case, Value

query = When(groups__name__in=[CUSTOMER_GROUP_NAME, ], then=Value(1))
qs2 = User.objects.annotate(
    is_customer=Case(query, default=Value(0), output_field=BooleanField()))
```

I think "Solution 2" is cleaner and easier to read. So I'll be using that :-)